# How to change Windows boot manager priority

Tags: windows-10, boot

I recently had to reinstall Windows 10 on my PC due to some issues, the problem is whenever I start my computer I always have to press F11 to select what Windows boots from. I have 4 options to select from to boot Windows:

1. Windows Boot Manager (P1: [Drive Name])
2. Windows Boot Manager (P5: [Drive Name])
3. [Drive Name]
4. [Drive Name]

All of the drive names are identical (I do have 2 HDDs but only 1 has any data on it, multiple formats of the spare drive have made sure of that). Windows can only boot from boot option 2 but by default, it tries to boot using boot option 1. I have managed to swap options 3 and 4 with 1 and 2 but I would need to swap 2 and 1 so the computer boots correctly without having to select the correct boot option.

I have been through the BIOS and boot order settings and I haven't been able to find a way to swap boot option 1 and option 2 around because they are group together as 'Windows Boot Manager'.

How would I go about swapping them?

Comment: You'd use [`BCDedit`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdedit) - I'd create an answer, but don't have the time at the moment

Answer (score 1):

`Start` > `Run` > `msconfig`

Go to the `Boot` tab. Choose a different drive, and click `Set as default`.

[image]

Comment: I have tried that as per a few online guides but msconfig only shows 1 drive, it is identical to the image you posted.